# redirect to Login?ReturnUrl=%2f in dnn

Tags: dotnetnuke

i have upgrade latest version of dnn. now i am unable to access another user menu while i click the menu button it will automatically redirect to login page.the error will show bellow

~/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2flynch%2fOrderProductDetail.aspx

but in super user account it is work fine.how to solve that issue.help me.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't appear to be an error, but likely something to do with mis-configured permissions.

I would start by checking the page permissions, make sure that the are configured properly (you likely want VIEW permissions for the "All Users" option)